# Replacing old capacitors?

Tags: capacitor

I am replacing a 4.7 uF 35v electrolytic axial leads capacitor near the cpu on an atari 2600. Can get away with using a 4.7 uF 50v capacitor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can .Using the higher volt is no problem.Many decades ago before I was born there were issues with forming voltages of electrolytic caps so you would sometimes see a minimum voltage written on the can along with the maximum voltage.